# In-universe, is there consistent science behind hyperspace travel?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars, hyperspace

It feels like the properties of hyperspace and hyperspace travel change depending on what's required to generate the most tension in the plot, but I'm wondering if there's any in-universe explanation about its properties.

For example, in Clone Wars S01E18, Anakin and Obi-Wan travel to Iego to get Reeksa root. The planet is "deep in Separatist space" and according to the map below, quite a long way from Naboo -

[image]

Yet Anakin and Obi-Wan get there pretty much instantly. You can tell because Ahsoka, Padme, Jar Jar and the clones are fighting droids in Dr Vindi's base, and send a transmission to Anakin and Obi-Wan which they receive after collecting the root.

However, in other episodes, ships don't arrive in time to support in battles because they have to plot long and complex hyperspace routes which take longer.

Is hyperspace consistent but dependant on routes, ship properties, type of hyperdrive, pilot skill, etc? Or is it is just altered depending on what best fits the plot?

Comment: Don't even get me started on 'lightspeed skipping'

Comment: Can you direct me to something that can get me started on 'lightspeed skipping'?

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/225690/what-is-lightspeed-skipping

Comment: [In Star Wars, sound can propagate through space](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1825/why-and-how-can-you-hear-explosions-in-space-in-star-wars), so if there is an explanation, you can't apply it to our universe.

Comment: @Spencer Actually, [sound does not propagate through space](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/102967/31936) and that's one of the few things Disney got right. It's when you include the sequel trilogy that you have ridiculous things like arcing weapons fire in space, 'lightspeed skipping', hyperspace ramming, etc.

Comment: [Relevant video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ov9uEArDlo&list=PLpO6zUJWB2uA2IMsWA0ZsckhUPq6b9zFB&index=16&t=0s)

Comment: @Null ohhh, DISney. Always spoiling the fun.

Comment: Great video, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Hyperspace is based off of a theory that if you take the fabric of space time, squish it so that you get one really tall peak instead of one really long stretch, then climb over the peak (which in star wars they travel straight through it), then flatten that peak of fabric out, voila! You are now hundreds of light years from where you started.

Now there is no way we can do that in real life sadly because we do not have 1) The computers to calculate exactly how far you have to squish the fabric and 2) we Don't have the power capability to jump through that peak of fabric.

Now in hyper space massive things such as planets and black holes can effect hyperspace travel which is why you need such a highly advanced computer system.

Also in star wars when han solo does random uncalculated jumps there is a heavy risk that they could have run into an active supernova or hit a planetary shadow, as such large objects throw gravitational shadows out in to hyper space

Comment: I don't know about *Star Wars* specifically, but that's not the traditional picture of "hyperspace."  Hyperspace is a space that is adjacent everywhere to normal space, but within which either distances are much less or speed is much higher.  What you're describing sounds more like a wormhole drive, where the "space" being traversed (if any) exists only for the duration of the travel, and is strictly point-to-point.

Comment: If we can't go to hyperspace in real life because we lack the computation, yet Han Solo can do uncalculated jumps, why can't we do uncalculated hyperspace jumps in real life?

Comment: BMF: we can't do jumps at all for another fact that the amount of power required to fold that fabric is absolutely in obtainable by far anything we have currently

Comment: Davidw: maybe your right you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Yet Anakin and Obi-Wan get there pretty much instantly. You can tell because Ahsoka, Padme, Jar Jar and the clones are fighting droids in Dr Vindi's base, and send a transmission to Anakin and Obi-Wan which they receive after collecting the root.

> However, in other episodes, ships don't arrive in time to support in battles because they have to plot long and complex hyperspace routes which take longer.

Needing a long time to make it seems to be mostly a mater of size. Huge ships like the Malevolence are pretty slow in hyperspace/have to plot a wide course to savely avoid all those small gravity wells that a fighter could easily avoid.

A small freighter - especially flown by a jedi who can rely on jedi pre-cognition to pick shortcuts - can pick a more direct route. But formation flights of a lot of small ships can make it a issue again. You kinda have to picture it like a large ship.

Another factor seems to be how well used/explored the route is. And how well used/explored for ships of that size. That the quick route exists for freighters is secondary, if you consider that for a miltiary operation you need *cruisers to battleships* and *acclamator sized troop transports* - they would not fit that route. At least not anywhere on that speed.

I think the best comparision is navigating rapids:

- a small Kajak can pass them at speed
- a ocean liner would propably not fit onto the river, much less pass them without ripping his hull open